# How can i solve the clang error when i use pip install

Tags: python, pip, odoo-12

When I execute

```
pip install -r requirements.txt -i https://pypi.doubanio.com/simple
```

There is an error:

```
clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include -DLIBART_COMPILATION -DLIBART_VERSION="2.3.12" -I/private/var/folders/4h/ktzb3kwn0zb24zppgz9hzzv80000gp/T/pip-build-l4jdu8pd/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM -I/private/var/folders/4h/ktzb3kwn0zb24zppgz9hzzv80000gp/T/pip-build-l4jdu8pd/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM/libart_lgpl -I/private/var/folders/4h/ktzb3kwn0zb24zppgz9hzzv80000gp/T/pip-build-l4jdu8pd/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM/gt1 -I/Users/xuhongxin/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/include/python3.6m -c /private/var/folders/4h/ktzb3kwn0zb24zppgz9hzzv80000gp/T/pip-build-l4jdu8pd/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM/gt1/gt1-namecontext.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.6/private/var/folders/4h/ktzb3kwn0zb24zppgz9hzzv80000gp/T/pip-build-l4jdu8pd/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM/gt1/gt1-namecontext.o
/private/var/folders/4h/ktzb3kwn0zb24zppgz9hzzv80000gp/T/pip-build-l4jdu8pd/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM/gt1/gt1-namecontext.c:100:9: error: implicitly declaring library function 'strlen' with type 'unsigned long (const char *)' [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    len = strlen (s);
        ^
/private/var/folders/4h/ktzb3kwn0zb24zppgz9hzzv80000gp/T/pip-build-l4jdu8pd/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM/gt1/gt1-namecontext.c:100:9: note: include the header <string.h> or explicitly provide a declaration for 'strlen'
/private/var/folders/4h/ktzb3kwn0zb24zppgz9hzzv80000gp/T/pip-build-l4jdu8pd/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM/gt1/gt1-namecontext.c:102:3: error: implicitly declaring library function 'memcpy' with type 'void *(void *, const void *, unsigned long)' [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    memcpy (new, s, len);
    ^
/private/var/folders/4h/ktzb3kwn0zb24zppgz9hzzv80000gp/T/pip-build-l4jdu8pd/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM/gt1/gt1-namecontext.c:102:3: note: include the header <string.h> or explicitly provide a declaration for 'memcpy'
/private/var/folders/4h/ktzb3kwn0zb24zppgz9hzzv80000gp/T/pip-build-l4jdu8pd/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM/gt1/gt1-namecontext.c:172:10: error: implicitly declaring library function 'strcmp' with type 'int (const char *, const char *)' [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    if (!strcmp (nc->table[i & mask].name, name))
            ^
/private/var/folders/4h/ktzb3kwn0zb24zppgz9hzzv80000gp/T/pip-build-l4jdu8pd/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM/gt1/gt1-namecontext.c:172:10: note: include the header <string.h> or explicitly provide a declaration for 'strcmp'
3 errors generated.
error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: Which specific package are you trying to install? What exactly is in your requirements.txt?

Answer (score 0):

Do not do it.

It can be done on the command line by setting compiler:

python setup.py build_ext -c

python setup.py build_ext --help-compiler to see available options.

However, the same compiler used to build the python distribution must be used for all extensions as the extension modules will be loaded by the interpreter.

If they are built by a different compiler, they cannot be safely loaded by the python interpreter.

In the case of Anaconda, its python distribution is built with MSVC, so the same compiler used by the anaconda environment should be used for extensions. In that case, activating the anaconda environment should suffice, though compiler can be set explicitly as above.

See Windows Compilers python wiki entry.

Comment: i execute "python setup.py build_ext --help-compiler"，the result is ：List of available compilers:
  --compiler=bcpp     Borland C++ Compiler
  --compiler=cygwin   Cygwin port of GNU C Compiler for Win32
  --compiler=mingw32  Mingw32 port of GNU C Compiler for Win32
  --compiler=msvc     Microsoft Visual C++
  --compiler=unix     standard UNIX-style compilerso whick compiler should  i use?